# How to link an framework generated by Cocoapods in a new iOS8 framework target

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, frameworks, cocoapods

I'm trying to create an iOS framework which I can use in many other iOS projects, and this 
framework has some dependencies, I need to use AFNetworking and Mantle libraries, I have 
created new project and podfile containing

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Mantle', '~> 2.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'
```

and I run pod install, after cocoapods generate an workspace, after that I add new target to my project
which is iOS8 framework, in this framework settings "General/Linked Frameworks and Libraries
click + butotn and select AFNetworking and Done, after i'm trying to build my project but I get 
this Error

> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-F/Users/borinschiivan/Desktop/ImodeveloperSDK/build/Debug-iphoneos/Pods'
>   ld: framework not found AFNetworking clang: error: linker command
>   failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

You can download this test project [here](http://d.pr/f/170gu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not do this step " in this framework settings in this framework settings, General/Linked Frameworks and Libraries click + button and select AFNetworking and Done"

All the linking would be done automatically by cocoa pods.

**Note**: Since you are building a library, read pod spec for creating reusable component. you can create your ImodeveloperKit as pod framework and specify AFNetowrking as a dependency for your framework in cocoa pod specification.

Edit: using link_with and specifying all the target solved the issue

Comment: Thanks, i found this on cocoapods guide https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#link_with

If no explicit target is specified, then the Pods target will be linked with the first target in your project. So if you only have one target you do not need to specify the target to link with.

This configuration `link_with 'ImodeveloperSDK', 'ImodeveloperKit'` in podfile solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
pod "AFNetworking", "~> 2.5"
```